# Is sequelize flawed? How to ensure independent DB connections in an Express server?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Ok, this is the situation:  I don't think there is a way to ensure independent DB connections for each HTTP request in a Node server that uses the `sequelize` NPM package.  I am currently using Express, so that's why I said "Express" in the title.  Allow me to explain my reasoning.

The `Sequelize` class is the one in charge of connecting to the database.  No problem so far, but then comes model initialization using either `Sequelize.define()` or `Model.init()`.  The former is a wrapper of the latter as per the documentation.

**The problem**:  `Model.init()` is a static method.  This means that it isn't tied to any instance.  This is the method that accepts the `Sequelize` instance.  I can only conclude that whichever instance is passed last to `Model.init()` is the one used to connect to the database.  Because this is not tied to any instance, it means that creating multiple `Sequelize` instances is just a futile exercise as the one used for all currently executing HTTP requests will be the one set by the most recent HTTP request.

My question here, to all of you:  Is this a bug or design oversight?  Or is there something I don't know about `sequelize` that would allow me to ensure independent database connections for each HTTP request?

Comment: [Docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/connection-pool/) say:  *If you're connecting to the database from a single process, you should create only one Sequelize instance. Sequelize will set up a connection pool on initialization.* I've never seen a db module for node.js that would require developers to create the pool themselves

Comment: @Konrad the pool is not the problem, I think.  I need to be ensured that individual HTTP requests use one connection.  For example, if an operation is a 2-step SQL operation, the same connection must be used to transact both.  How can I be assured that the operation of ModelA and ModelB will run using the same connection?

Comment: If you have 2 SQL operations then you most likely need to use an explicit transaction (and that of course means the same connection).